# Nested ngFor select not clickable

Tags: angular, ngfor

I'm using ngFor to make a questions, and in those questions I'm using another ngFor to show the posibble answer with a radio button beside each answer.

Everything is generated correctly and if I click on the radio of any answer in the first question, everything goes well.

The problem arrives when I try to click on the answers of the second question, if I click on any of these, the radio buttons of the first questions are checked.

Here's the code I have right now.

```
<div id="question{{questionInd}}" class="card bg-blue-grey bg-lighten-5" *ngFor="let question of focusGroup.aptitudeTest.questions; let questionInd = index">
    <div class="card-header"><span class="text-bold-500 primary">¿{{question.question}}?</span></div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="card-block">
            <div *ngFor="let answer of question.answers; let answerInd = index" class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                <input type="radio" id="answer{{answerInd}}" [value]="answer.answer" name="desiredAnswerRadio{{questionInd}}" class="custom-control-input" (change)="desiredAnswer(question, answer)">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="answer{{answerInd}}">
                    <span class="display-block"><i class="ft-minus"></i> {{answer.answer}}</span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The following pictures are meant as a visual guide of what I explained before.

[Questions and answers displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3Gjp.png)

[This happened when I clicked the answer ***Yes***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7s6w.png)

[This happened when I clicked the answer ***Certainly not***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9YTH.png)

Edit:

As per request, this is the ***desiredAnswer*** method.

```
desiredAnswer(question: ITestQuestion, desiredAnswer: ITestAnswerOption) {
    question.answers.forEach(function(answer: ITestAnswerOption) {
        answer.desired = false;
    });
    desiredAnswer.desired = true;
    console.log(question.answers);
}
```

Since I only need one answer and each radio button is linked to a property of an answer using ***ngModel***, in the method I set all to false and then set the desired one to ***true***.

Comment: Could you please tell me what's inside of `desiredAnswer()`?

Comment: So far it looks okay according to this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d4nbbm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) and yes what is inside desiredAnswer as @JosefKatič asked

Comment: This is what's inside desired answer:

desiredAnswer(question: ITestQuestion, desiredAnswer: ITestAnswerOption) {
    question.answers.forEach(function(answer: ITestAnswerOption) {
       answer.desired = false;
    });
    desiredAnswer.desired = true;
    console.log(question.answers);
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, I don't know why this solved it, but i just changed this line:

```
<input type="radio" id="answer{{answerInd}}" [value]="answer.answer" name="desiredAnswerRadio{{questionInd}}" class="custom-control-input" (change)="desiredAnswer(question, answer)">
```

To this:

```
<input type="radio" id="answer{{answer.id}}" name="desiredAnswerRadio{{question.id}}" class="custom-control-input" (change)="desiredAnswer(question, answer)">
```

And now it works just fine, I can click on the radio buttons of both questions.

[Both questions answered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uO0qC.png)

Just figured it out, I was setting the id of each radio with the index of the nested ngfor, but it repeated each new question since the index of the nested ngfor started again at 0.
Hence why using the id of each answer inmediately worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider the javascript object scope. In the `desiredAnswer` function `question.answers.forEach(function(answer: ITestAnswerOption) {` the `answer: ITestAnswerOption` object is not the same object that you are passing to the function to set `desiredAnswer.desired = true;` so the function should look like this

```
desiredAnswer(question: ITestQuestion, desiredAnswer: ITestAnswerOption) {
  question.answers.forEach(function(answer: ITestAnswerOption) {
    if (desiredAnswer == answer) answer.desired = true;
    else answer.desired = false;
  });
  console.log(question.answers);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realized this, but it isn't really the problem I had.